# Как связать две таблицы взяв только первое значение?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

Как вывести все значения из таблицы `exchanges` и при этом взять только одно связующее `активное` поле из таблицы `accounts` по полю `exchange_id` ?

Результат должен быть из 5 полей.

2 таблицы:

```
exchanges
id  name   class  active
1   test   Test   1
2   test2  Test2  1
3   test3  Test3  1
4   test4  Test4  1
5   test5  Test5  1


accounts
id  exchange_id name    active
1   1           Sergey  1
2   1           Oleg    1
3   2           Sergey  1
4   3           Sergey  1
5   4           Sergey  1
6   5           Sergey  1
```

SQL запрос:

```
    "SELECT a.id, e.name, e.class, a.exchange_id, a.id as account_id, a.name as account_name 
FROM exchanges as e 
LEFT JOIN accounts as a ON (a.exchange_id = e.id) 
WHERE a.active = 1 AND e.active = 1"
```

Результат:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "test"
    ["class"]=>
    string(7) "Test"
    ["exchange_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["account_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["account_name"]=>
    string(1) "Sergey"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "test2"
    ["class"]=>
    string(5) "Test2"
    ["exchange_id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["account_id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["account_name"]=>
    string(1) "Sergey"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "test3"
    ["class"]=>
    string(6) "Test3"
    ["exchange_id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["account_id"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["account_name"]=>
    string(1) "Sergey"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "test4"
    ["class"]=>
    string(5) "Test4"
    ["exchange_id"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["account_id"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["account_name"]=>
    string(1) "Sergey"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["name"]=>
    string(9) "test5"
    ["class"]=>
    string(9) "Test5"
    ["exchange_id"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["account_id"]=>
    string(1) "6"
    ["account_name"]=>
    string(1) "Sergey"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "6"
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "test"
    ["class"]=>
    string(7) "Test"
    ["exchange_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["account_id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["account_name"]=>
    string(1) "Oleg"
  }
}
```

Здесь одно лишнее, это:

```
[5]=>
  array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "6"
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "test"
    ["class"]=>
    string(7) "Test"
    ["exchange_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["account_id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["account_name"]=>
    string(1) "Oleg"
  }
```

Comment: Откуда этот вывод данных? Это явно не SQL вывод.

Comment: @SwaD это про результат? это просто обычный в php var_dump

Comment: Это легко можно решить на php, но хотелось бы это сделать через sql запрос

Comment: Покажите результат в SQL

Comment: Он уже есть в вопросе

Comment: *2 таблицы* Ни о чём. Дайте их в виде CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO. *Он уже есть в вопросе* Нет, запрос возвращает не PHP-дамп, а таблицу. Вот её и показывайте. *SQL запрос* Во-первых, неплохо бы рассказать, что запрос ДОЛЖЕН сделать. Во-вторых, нафига LEFT JOIN, если ты его потом своими же руками превращаешь в INNER?